# Store new document to specific collection in RavenDB via REST

Tags: powershell, ravendb, ravendb-http

I'm **uploading documents to RavenDB from PowerShell** script. Here it is:

```
$Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToBinary()
$Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/databases/DiskStat/docs"

$diskObject = New-Object PSObject @{
    "@metadata" = New-Object psobject @{
        "Raven-Entity-Name" = "Entries"
    }
    Timestamp = $Timestamp
    Computer = $comp
    Disk = $disk.DeviceID
    Size = $disk.Size
    Free = $disk.FreeSpace
}
[string]$diskJson = (ConvertTo-Json $diskObject)
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Put -Body $diskJson | Out-Null
```

The **problem** is that **new documents do not belong to any collection**, **`@metadata` is ignored**. Documents are looking like this in database:

```
{
  "Size": 52427931648,
  "Timestamp": -8588258377456088029,
  "Computer": "710H0001",
  "Free": 27922563072,
  "Disk": "C:",
  "@metadata": {
    "@id": "423b5bdf-fe59-4530-8047-bc48d98ee363",
    "Last-Modified": "2013-08-06T06:05:42.6982277Z",
    "@etag": "00000001-0000-a900-0000-000000000001",
    "Non-Authoritative-Information": false
  }
}
```

So I have to patch it from time to time to assign `Raven-Entity-Name`. Cool RavenDB guys, please, help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While metadata is returned in the `@metadata` section, that's not how you send it in.  That's because you don't have control over every metadata value.  For example, passing in an etag wouldn't make sense.

Instead, for the metadata values you *can* control, send them in the HTTP headers.

```
$headers = @{"Raven-Entity-Name"="Entries"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this is not clear from [RavenDB HTTP API documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api)